# I'm using Winnovative to output Excel file. But I can not set Zoom View of Excel (not zoom scale for print)

Tags: c#, excel, winnovative

I'm using Winnovative library to output Excel file (C# .NET). But I can not set Zoom View of Excel 80% instead of default value 100% of excel file.
Note: it is not zoom scale for print.

If you know how to set, please help me!
Thank you

Comment: So you don't know the property to use? Or do you have code which doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know the property to use. It is Zoom Slider in excel file. Maybe Winnovative library is not existing this property.